# Unable to inject javascript with Swashbuckle/Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using the Swashbuckle NuGet package to create Swagger documentation for my API. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle

I'm trying to make some minor changes to the UI - essentially just to add some corporate branding to the header.

I have added two files as embedded resources to my project, in a directory called resources.

These are injected into the UI via:

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
{
    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, typeof(SwaggerConfig).Namespace + ".Resources.Swagger.css");

    c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, typeof(SwaggerConfig).Namespace + ".Resources.Swagger.js");
}
```

Which results in the following link being added to rendered page.

```
<link href="ext/ang_nav_api-Resources-Swagger-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

This is all correct and the stylesheet works as expected.

However the .js script doesn't appear on the client.

Changing the `c.InjectJavaScript` to `c.InjectStylesheet` does inject the file as a `<link>` .. so I'm happy that the file itself is correctly embedded etc.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .js script will not appear on the client. (not on the way you would expect)
Look closely to the code of index.html:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/8223bedae706fec612c98ebbcee6b2d7033ae349/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html#L98

Your customScripts will be loaded dynamically on the onComplete event

```
$.getScript(script);
```

Comment: And if all you need is some minor changes to the UI, a custom CSS should be enough, take a look at this example:
http://swashbuckletest.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index

Comment: Thanks, sorry this took a back seat so only just come back to it. @Helder The Custom CSS will do 99% of what I want... it might do 100%. All I need to do is add a branding logo and switch some colours. Its adding the logo that I wanted the script for as I actually need a new DOM node.

Comment: Finally got this to work. It would seem that as I had wrapped my code in $(document).ready(function(){}), it wasn't executing.